# How do I change the color of ellipse to a randint every two seconds in Kivy, using random integers

Tags: python, colors, kivy

```
class CanvasExample5(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ball_size = dp(50)
        with self.canvas:
            self.color = Color(0, 1, 0)
            self.ball = Ellipse(pos=self.center, size=(self.ball_size, self.ball_size))
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.colour, 1)
        self.vx = dp(5)
        self.vy = dp(3)

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.ball.pos = (self.center_x-self.ball_size/2, self.center_y-self.ball_size/2)

    def colour(self, *args):
        random_1 = random.randint(0, 255)
        random_2 = random.randint(0, 255)
        random_3 = random.randint(0, 255)
        self.color = Color(random_1, random_2, random_3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ellipse` graphics command uses the `Color` that is in effect at the time it is executed, so changing the `Color` afterwards will have no effect on the `Ellipse`. One fix is to clear the canvas and redraw the `Ellipse` with the new `Color`:

```
def colour(self, *args):
    random_1 = random.random()
    random_2 = random.random()
    random_3 = random.random()
    self.canvas.clear()
    with self.canvas:
        Color(random_1, random_2, random_3)
        self.ball = Ellipse(pos=self.center, size=(self.ball_size, self.ball_size))
```

Also, note that the `Color` command takes values between 0 and 1, not 0 to 255.